# How To Customise wp_nav_menu

Tags: wordpress, styles, themes, customization

I am developing a wordpress theme and I am trying to add a top menu below the title.

I am using the wp_nav_menu which displays the pages properly but I do not know how to style it.

Answer (score 3):

The [options are described in the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu). You could simply copy/paste the example code and add your own classes and IDs, like I do below:

```
<?php $defaults = array( 
 'container_class' => 'my-container-class', 
 'container_id'    => 'my-container-id',
 'menu_class'      => 'my-menu', 
 'menu_id'         => 'my-menu-id',
 'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
); ?>

<?php wp_nav_menu( $defaults ); ?>
```

The %1$s and similar are explained in the $items_wrap section. Essentially they are for choosing where you want these custom classes and IDs in the code.
Once it's all set, open your style.css file and start the fun.

```
.my-container-class {
 /* set your rules here */
}

#my-container-id {
 /* and so on... */
}
```

The other, simpler option, only requires any [code inspector](http://getfirebug.com) and some basic knowledge of css. The IDs and classes generated by Wordpress would be enough to do the trick.

Comment: It should be simple to add 'myColour' to each li element but this is not easy to understand sorry. I understand %1$s but where can I add my own custom class name.

Comment: This answer is several years old, so I can't confirm if it's still applicable to the current version of Wordpress. The first value of the array in the example has the custom class.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find the css classes of each individual element so you can set the styles on your CSS file:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Menu_Item_CSS_Classes

Comment: Yes thanks - from my recent look in there you can wrap the whole menu but not individual items and you need a custom walker class to do that.