# How to style a menu/nav to go horizontal with CSS using PHP?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, styling

I am really new to PHP coding so please let me know if anything I'm asking doesn't make sense. I have followed some tutorials and have written this php code to form a navigation through a local wordpress website to create a new theme.

I am now trying to style the theme, this is the code for the navigation:

```
    <div id="nav"><?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme location'=>'primary')); ?></div>
```

I am so confused as to how you would style this menu horizontally as I would normally use the unordered list and list item tags in html to display it inline etc. But these tags are not available to use with php.

If anyone could explain how I would do this I would be very grateful!

Comment: Not to be rude but this question lacks specifics of your problems P.S I did not downvote

Comment: Did you try inline-block? Are you sure you don't have conflicting style sheets?

Comment: Yeah that didn't work. Sorry if its vague I am very new to this. This is code refering to a menu made within wordpress. I am trying to style this inline but I would normally use the unordered list and list item tags to style it as I normally need access to each list item to display it correctly inline. However as this code just refers to a menu made in wordpress that can be altered within wordpress, it means I don't get access to each individual list item within the code to use for the css tags. Just wondering how to do that. Sorry if that still isn't very clear. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I've only got one style sheet, and nothing is styling this menu yet.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. I remember having similar frustrations when I started out. You can still target the list items and such generated by wordpress but the way they do it is a pain. I used something called a walker to custom generate list items and 'ul's but that's a little more php than I care to get in to right now. Search for wordpress navigation walker... that might set you on the right track. That is, if I'm understanding you correctly.

Comment: wait... is this project hosted locally on your machine or is it online already?

Comment: local on my machine

Comment: Okay thank you for the help I will check navigation walker out!

Comment: Can you post the viewsource code for the navigation section please?

Comment: See the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12780078/how-to-customise-wp-nav-menu

Comment: Stuart for the win

Comment: Thanks Stuart you are a legend!

Comment: He lucyisobel I think stuart gave you what you need but that code you posted is not the viewsource just so you know. I meant please post the code after the php has run and been rendered by the browser but that's okay. Stuart's method should work.

Comment: Contact Me
About Me
Home
Blog

not sure if that is the viewsource code sorry guys not grasped all the terms yet. That is the menu that is created in the browser. 

Thanks for all the help reading the article now

Comment: `.menu-item{ display:block; float:left; padding: 5px; margin: 0 15px;}` there is a lot more then that that you will need.  It took me 2 days to do my menu ( http://www.artisticphoenix.com/ ), and I been doing this a long time.  (that said I puts some special features in my menu ... lol )

Comment: Okay that worked! thank you very much ArtisticPhoenix!! Thanks everyone for the help I really appreciate it, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Sure, basically you have to float the items, but the `<li>` is an inline tag, so you have to make it block first,  you could do it many different ways, like `inline-block`  maybe with `flex` (something I need to play with more)  there is no real right answer.  Floating is the old school way, but it works in pretty much every browser.

Answer (score 0):

In html - find the ul with the navigation links -> CSS - use display:inline for li elements within the ul.

This will transpose the links.